# Performed FFT on an audio signal, but what does the output actually mean?

Tags: fft

Original post from yesterday [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27609/performed-the-danielson-lanczos-shuffling-for-fft-but-i-dont-know-what-to-do-n)

So I did the FFT and I have my transformed data (which is a bunch of values for each frame of data. I'm unsure what the transformed data actually represents. What information do I need, and what math do I need to perform to turn the $k$ values into the appropriate frequency values and the $X[k]$ values into $\textrm{dB}$ values? With $X[k]$ being equal to the sum of $x[n]$ from $n$ to $N-1$ times [...]

I understand how the FFT algorithm works now, I'm just not real clear on what the actual results represent.

Comment: This is probably best answered by a text book on the matter.

Comment: Liz, do you understand that the FFT is a (fast) method of computing the DFT?  can you write down the equation that defines the DFT, that expresses $X[k]$ in terms of $x[n]$?  then write down the equation that is the inverse DFT (that tells you what $x[n]$ is in terms of the $X[k]$ you've just computed.  that last equation tells you what the output of the DFT (that is $X[k]$) fundamentally mean.

Comment: Do you know the sample rate at which your original samples of data were taken?

Comment: 44.100kHz. I'm processing wave files, and some are at other sample rates but I can parse that information from the file, it's listed at the beginning of ever wave file in hex. I think, after a bit more digging, that these 'bins', multiplied by sampleRate/frameLength (so in my case, 44100/4096) give the actual frequencies that correspond to the modulus power levels. A bit more math converts the frequencies to musical notes. I guess the only thing I haven't figured out is how to turn the X[k] levels into dB. It's my understanding that I need a 'reference level'? What would that be for audio?

Comment: are you trying to make a audio-to-MIDI converter?

Comment: no, i've already done what i need to with midi files. i'm basically making something similar to the bouncing bar graphs on the front of stereo displays when I was younger. it takes the frequency information and displays it in a novel way over time. at least thats what this component of the project entails. there's other processing to be done on the frequency data later according to the design requirements.

and for anyone that stumbles on this later, the bin number (k) is related to actual frequency by sampleRate*k/frameSize.